# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

I have checked some number of links to get understanding the cause of the error but not fixing my issue.

I am trying to access WebAPi action from Postman but getting the below error.

> "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50684/api/albums/history'.",
>     "messageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'album'."

My API.

```
[Authorize]
public class AlbumsController : ApiController
{

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("api/album/history/")]
   public BaseTO GetHistory(string type,int id)
   {  
      //api stuff
   }
 }
```

I tried with `api/album/history/{anything}`

While making call from Postman I am passing:-

- Authorization Token
- Type
- Id

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: have you enabled attribute routing in api config? `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

Comment: URL and error message don't match up. it shows that URL is looking for `AlbumController` but the URL has albums (plural)

Comment: can you try with http://localhost:50684/api/albums/history?type=a&id=1
and also are you adding Authorization Token in the Header while making request from Postman?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you enabled attribute routing in api config? `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

With your current route, you should hit it via query string `http://localhost:50684/api/albums/history?type=test&id=1` and decorate the parameters with `[FromUri]`

```
[HttpGet]
   [Route("api/albums/history/")]
   public IHttpActionResult GetHistory([FromUri]string type,[FromUri]int id)
   {  
      //api stuff
   }
```

or to hit the api via route parameters - `http://localhost:50684/api/albums/history/test/1`

```
[HttpGet]
   [Route("api/albums/history/{type}/{id}")]
   public IHttpActionResult GetHistory(string type,int id)
   {  
      //api stuff
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I just changed this :

AllowInsecureHttp = true

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);


        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),                
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Code should be like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class AlbumsController : ApiController
{

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("api/albums/history/")]
   public IHttpActionResult GetHistory(string type,int id)
   {  
      //api stuff
   }
 }
```

and your call from Postman should be like this and make sure your method in Postman is GET:

http://localhost:50684/api/album/history?type=test&id=1

hope it will help you.

Comment: You updated return type? How does it make any difference??

Comment: IHttpActionResult will come in handy is when you’d like to preset specific headers/properties of HTTP response. For example, when responding to a POST request, you’d like to automatically set the status code to 201 (created) and set the location header.

Comment: hey @Kgn-web can you elaborate what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Note that the route definied includes the string "albums" but in the url for calling the endpoint its written "album"

Comment: that ONLY works for query strings, not for typical routes - you need: api/albums/history/{type}/{id}